# How to use plugins in php mvc framework

Tags: editor

I want to know that , i am using my own (modal view controller) framework and want       to add some plugins like live chatting ,Facebook/g-mail/twitter (sign up/sign in    using these websites).
type of features how can i do this?
I am novice in this field so sorry in advance if my question has some stupidity.
I am using notepad++ editor.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use observer pattern or Event dispatcher pattern for plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look **how other frameworks allow you to implement these features**.

If one of those features just need js/css and custom html markup to work (like a Facebook like-button for example), you might find some inspiration from Zend Framework's View Helpers.

Search through github/packagist if one of those features has not yet been developed. If you find some library, find a way to use it in your custom code.